# Plupload set parameter after init

Tags: javascript, plupload

So I basically want to set the filename parameter once the upload button has been clicked and I have got the filename from another function.

```
var uploader = new plupload.Uploader({
    runtimes : 'html5,flash,silverlight,html4',
    browse_button : 'pickfiles', // you can pass an id...
    container: document.getElementById('container'), // ... or DOM Element itself
    url : 'upload.php',
    chunk_size: '200kb',
    flash_swf_url : '../js/Moxie.swf',
    silverlight_xap_url : '../js/Moxie.xap',
  multipart_params : {
        "filename" : filename,

    },

    filters : {
        max_file_size : '1000mb',
        mime_types: [
            {title : "Image files", extensions : "jpg,gif,png"},
            {title : "Zip files", extensions : "zip"}
        ]
    },

    init: {
        PostInit: function() {
            document.getElementById('filelist').innerHTML = '';

            document.getElementById('uploadfiles').onclick = function() {

        // Filename function is not in here but it will return a filename
        var filename = get_filename_from_function();
        // Set filename ?
                uploader.start();
                return false;
            };
        },

        FilesAdded: function(up, files) {
            plupload.each(files, function(file) {
                document.getElementById('filelist').innerHTML += '<div id="' + file.id + '">' + file.name + ' (' + plupload.formatSize(file.size) + ') <b></b></div>';
            });
        },

        UploadProgress: function(up, file) {
            document.getElementById(file.id).getElementsByTagName('b')[0].innerHTML = '<span>' + file.percent + "%</span>";
        },

        Error: function(up, err) {
            document.getElementById('console').appendChild(document.createTextNode("\nError #" + err.code + ": " + err.message));
        }
    }
});

uploader.init();
```

get_filename_from_function() will return a filename which I then want to set as a multipart parameter that will post to the PHP file however I can't seem to figure it out. It always says filename not defined.

Answer (score 0):

```
init: {
        PostInit: function() {
            document.getElementById('filelist').innerHTML = '';

            document.getElementById('uploadfiles').onclick = function() {

        // Filename function is not in here but it will return a filename
        var filename = get_filename_from_function();
        // set the filename here
        uploader.settings.multipart_params.filename = filename ;
                uploader.start();
                return false;
            };
        }
```

I seem to have found the answer to my own question. The magical line of code which should be placed in the onclick function is:

```
uploader.settings.multipart_params.filename = filename ;
```

Also make sure that multipart_params are not declared in the uploader function.

```
multipart_params : {
        "filename" : filename,

    },
// Make sure to remove this from the original function
```

Hope it helps someone , took some time to find.